# converting to MT timestamp - HIVE

Tags: hive, mt

I want to convert a given timestamp to MT (Mountain Time) timestamp in HIVE. What is the easiest way to achieve this? Consideting today I am executing my code from PST but the code can be executed from central timestamp. Irrespective of from where the code is getting executed, I want to convert the input timestamp to MT timestamp. Also in some cases the timestamp is 0, so that also need to be handled.

Comment: What does your timestamp currently look like?  Is time zone part of it?

Comment: no it is YYYY-MM-DD HHMISS format only